# Object.defineProperty is letting me enumerate prototyped properties but Object.keys doesn't include that property, what gives?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible for the snippet below to get `Object.keys` to include the prototyped properties (e.g. *health*)?

**NOTE: I need the health property defined AFTER the definition of the class.**

```js
class Player {
  constructor(level) {
    this.level = level;
  }
}

const player = new Player(10);

Object.defineProperty(Player.prototype, "health", {
  enumerable: true,
  get: function() {
    return this.level * 15;
  }
});

console.log(player.health);

console.log(Object.keys(player)); // not showing health

for (let prop in player) {
  console.log(prop);
}
```

If not, how would I go about adding a property to the `Player` class that has the health property so that I can get the two properties from any created objects?

Answer (score 2):

`Object.keys` will only ever return an array of keys that are *directly on the instance*. Any keys that are on the prototype will be ignored. Although you could use a `for..in` loop to get all enumerable keys anywhere on the prototype chain, you would probably be better off calling `defineProperty` on the *instance*, in the constructor, to assign the getter property:

```js
class Player {
  constructor(level) {
    this.level = level;
    Object.defineProperty(this, "health", {
      enumerable: true,
      get: function() {
        console.log('Inside the get function');
        return this.level * 15;
      }
    });
  }
}

const player = new Player(10);


console.log(player.health);
console.log(Object.keys(player));

for (let prop in player) {
  console.log(prop);
}
```

If you have to use `defineProperty` outside the class, then call it on the instance after it's been created:

```js
class Player {
  constructor(level) {
    this.level = level;
  }
}

const player = new Player(10);
Object.defineProperty(player, "health", {
  enumerable: true,
  get: function() {
    console.log('Inside the get function');
    return player.level * 15;
  }
});

console.log(player.health);
console.log(Object.keys(player));

for (let prop in player) {
  console.log(prop);
}
```

Still, this is a pretty weird thing to do, especially for a property that doesn't sound like it's dynamic, like `health`. I'd prefer using an ordinary `get health() {` method instead.

Comment: I need to add the property outside of the class definition, is this possible?

Comment: You can call it on the instance after it's created, but it's pretty weird.

Comment: It has to be an instance in this case? Is it possible to have this be on the class not an instance of the class? I think maybe forcing the constructor to create the property would work like you have in the first example by overriding the defined constructor with () => {`call defined constructor` then `call Object.defineProperty`}. Health is just an example, in reality the properties I'm defining are far more dynamic than this.

Comment: You can wrap the class in a function that, when called, instantiates an object, assigns the getter, and returns the instance, if you want. There's no way around having to assign to the instance itself *somewhere* (either inside the constructor, or after the constructor has run), because `Object.keys` will only iterate over properties directly on the instance. (you could iterate over the *prototype* as well as the instance, if you wanted, though)